# Reinstalled RVM after an implode, but now command 'rvm' isn't found

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, linux-mint

When trying to install Ruby 2.7.7 for one of my projects, I ran into an `error while running make install. Installation halted` message. Since then I have tried a lot of different things I found on google, including imploding RVM and reinstalling, and now I get the message `command 'rvm' not found, but there are 19 similar ones.` I admit I somewhat blindly followed solutions I found on here and github, but nothing really worked.

Here is the output from `grep -rn rvm ~/.bash*`:

```
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:259:rvm which ruby
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:260:rvm rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:280:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:281:rvm install 2.7.7
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:282:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:283:/usr/share/rvm/log/1677601373_ruby-2.7.7/install.log
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:284:nano /usr/share/rvm/log/1677601373_ruby-2.7.7/install.log
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:285:rvm --ruby-version use 2.7.7
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:286:rvm --ruby-version use 2.7.7 --create
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:287:nano /usr/share/rvm/log/1677601373_ruby-2.7.7/install.log
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:289:rvm install 2.7.0 --with-openssl-dir=path/to/openssl@1.1
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:290:nano /usr/share/rvm/log/1677602005_ruby-2.7.0/make.log
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:296:rvm info rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:297:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:298:rvm use default
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:299:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:302:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:303:type cd | head -1 ; type rvm | head -1
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:307:rvm pkg install openssl
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:308:rvm reinstall all --force
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:309:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:310:rvm remove 2.7.7
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:311:rvm install "ruby-3.2.0"
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:312:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:313:rvm install "ruby-2.7.7"
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:314:rvm install make
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:315:rvm get master
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:317:rvm install gpg
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:320:command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:321:rvm get master
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:322:command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import -
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:324:command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import -
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:325:rvm get master
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:326:rvm remove 2.7.7
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:327:CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install 2.7.7
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:333:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:334:rvm --ruby-version use 2.7.7
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:335:rvm --ruby-version use 2.7.7 --create
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:342:rvm implode
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:374:ls rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:375:rm rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:376:sudo rm -rf rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:380:tree usr/share/rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:383:if sudo grep -q secure_path /etc/sudoers; then sudo sh -c "echo export rvmsudo_secure_path=1 >> /etc/profile.d/rvm_secure_path.sh" && echo Environment variable installed; fi
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:384:sudo usermod -a -G rvm `whoami`
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:388:rvm install ruby

##I believe this was where I got the first 'rvm' not found message##

/home/ladygund/.bash_history:390:curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:391:command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | sudo gpg2 --import -
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:392:rvm install ruby
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:397:rvm list
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:399:sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:401:sudo apt-get install rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:402:sudo usermod -a -G rvm $USER
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:403:rvm list
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:404:echo 'source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"' >> ~/.bashrc
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:405:rvm list
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:407:sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:409:sudo apt-get install rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:411:sudo usermod -a -G rvm $USER
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:412:rvm list
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:413:echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:415:rvm list
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:416:echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.profile
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:417:rvm list
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:420:echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:428:rvm install ruby
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:436:rvm install ruby
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:441:rvm list
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:447:ls /usr/share/rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:449:ls /usr/share/rvm/src/
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:451:rvm install ruby
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:470:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:485:ls rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:486:ls rvm -la
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:490:grep -rn rvm ~/.bash*
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:491:rvm get master
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:493:nano /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh 
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:494:sudo nano /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh 
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:495:rvm get master
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:496:sudo nano /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh 
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:498:rvm list rubies
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:499:rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:500:rvm
```

I found what I thought was a solution to the `error while running make install` problem, which I think was to install `openssl` via rvm and then reinstall the 3 versions of ruby I needed. That did not solve it.
I found a couple of solutions that involved installing gpg2 and then running the `command curl` commands. That did not solve anything.
So I removed 2.7.7 and reinstalled using `CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install 2.7.7`, which I found *somewhere* but have no idea where. That did not work.
The only thing left that I could think of was to remove RVM and reinstall it. And now, we are here, where nothing has been solved and I am only getting more confused.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!
Hey - I totally get the feeling of wildly thrashing around trying to find a solution :D
I dunno how much i can help, but I'll see what i can do.
Firstly, this part: `/home/ladygund/.bash_history:375:rm rvm
/home/ladygund/.bash_history:376:sudo rm -rf rvm` is where you tried to delete rvm, but rvm is not a directory or file, so that won't work properly.

Comment: How did you first install rvm? and what O/S are you on?
Are you on Mac? if so: do you use homebrew to install things?
I definitely agree that uninstall rvm would be a good place to start - start with a clean slate. Then reinstall rvm and install the ruby you need.